# Clone your google chrome into Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to "clone" my personal google chrome into a driver with selenium wedriver (python)?
For example I would like that my google account, which is already logged in my google chrome, will be logged in the new driver too.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: most likely not and if it is, you might go against the test rules. The reason why is that the selenium has no cache after you closed the app ... the reason why (in my opinion) is to make all the tests work as it would for a normal user anywhere in the world. If you could clone your chrome into it, you will be testing it on a specific platform and thats mostly something what you do not want to do. If its only for your personal use then go ahead and give it a try, if you want it to test a product, i hight recommend you to not do that

Comment: @StyleZ he just want t okeep the session aline , for that you can use the chrome user profile .

Comment: The below answer will keep all your settings and cookies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type : chrome://version in address bar

[image]

add this as user-data-dir argument, don't add the last path ('default' in the given example)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\Users\guest\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```